# TortoiseGit - reset a folder to original files

Tags: git, tortoisegit

My files are not pushing, I continue to receive error 128 when I enter:

```
git push
```

At this point, all I am looking to do is **reset the entire folder** where the files are to the original form (how it appears globally not locally). How do I do this?

Note: I already saved the files to a local drive incase I want to retrieve my local versions

Comment: What exact message do you get? I'm quite sure it's not related to the working tree state.

Comment: Restore a folder or restore the entire working tree? There is a huge difference.

Answer (score 2):

Right click in your working copy to get the contextual menu.
Do a Fetch to get the latest changes from the repository.

Again, go in the contextual menu.
Select "Switch/Checkout" (it might be in the TortoiseGit submenu).
For the Branch, select "remotes//"
(by default nameOfRemote would be "origin")
Create New Branch should be checked and have the name of your current local branch.
Check "Overwrite working tree changes (force)".
Check "Override branch if exists".
Go!

This will reset any local changes and reset the local branch to the latest commit of the remote branch. It does not seem to remove untracked files or ignored files.

Answer (score 1):

Open the log dialog and on the top most entry "working tree chanes" select fetch on the context menu.

After that you can select the latest remote commit (labeled with "remotes/origin", you might need to select all branches the lower left OR you can click in the upper left and select the remote branch) and select reset on the context menu. In the following dialog select "hard" - this will drop any uncommitted changes to files and also local commits which are not yet pushed.

After these steps your working tree is exactly at the state of the
Remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to reset to the latest commit on the local branch is to use the command `git reset --hard` inside your directory, on the command line.

If you want to align with what is in the remote repository (**this will destroy your local commits**).

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following two commands to clean and start over from the latest commit.

```
git clean -fd
git reset --hard
```